# Ошибка в gulp, при формировании sprit'ов

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, спрайт

Доброго времени суток, при запросе на формировании спрайта возникает ошибка. Собственно код ниже для формирования. А ошибка "events.js:160 throw er; // Unhadled 'error' event Error: Streaming not supported
Спасибо

```
gulp.task('sprite', function () {
var spriteData = gulp.src(config.src + 'images/sprite/*.png')
    .pipe(spritesmith({
        imgName: 'sprite.png',
        cssName: 'Sprite.less',
        cssFormat: 'less',
        padding: 5,
        cssVarMap: function (sprite) {
            sprite.name = 'icon-' + sprite.name;
        },
        imgPath: config.src + 'images/sprite.png'
    }));

spriteData.img
    .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.src + 'images/'));

spriteData.css
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.src + 'less/'));

return spriteData;
```

});

Comment: Покажите ошибку полностью. Может быть проблема в imagemin и что он не работает с потоком, а только с уже готовым файлом, попробуйте вынести imagemin в отдельный таск.

Comment: Действительно ошибка была в imagemin, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вынесите `imagemin` в отдельный таск, так как этот плагин не может работать с потоком.

Comment: Зачем вы переписали мой комментарий?

Comment: Чтобы у вопроса был ответ, очевидно.

Comment: Я и сам мог бы оформить комментарий, как ответ.

Comment: greybutton, до последнего вас ждал, чтобы вы ответили на вопрос, не отдавал никому баллы(

Comment: @greybutton не видел вообще вашего коммента. Я смотрю на вопрос и ответы. Не знал, что вы давали ответ в комментах.